# Development Methodologies

Tags: agile, modeling, object-oriented-analysis

I am having some confusion on what is a development methodology.

For example, take the following:
Waterfall model
Iterative & Incremental
Unified Process
Extreme Programming
Dynamic  system development method

Which of these are development methods etc. From my understanding waterfall and iterative & incremental are models used by the different methods (UF, XP, DSDM)
Is this correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as defined in the [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two important concepts to grasp. The first one is the definition of project. From the PMI definition:

> "A project can be defined as a temporary endeavor undertaken to create
>   a unique product or service"

So, there are some project management and planning styles (or models). This is where it comes the sequential model, the iterative model, etc. These models describe a set of practices and techniques lead your project from the beginning to the end.

And there is **a kind of** project that is the software development project. It means a project where the end of it is the delivery of a software.

To that **kind of** projects there are some specialisations of the former models. For example there is the Waterfall model following the sequential model and extreme programming (XP) following the iterative model.

These specialisations translate some of the techniques described in the "generic" models to match development processes and also incorporate other practices.